# How to change the drive reference in a zfs pool from /dev/sdX to /dev/disk/by-id (ata-XXXXXX)

Tags: linux, zfs, ubuntu-16.04, zfsonlinux

In the example below, how can the devices in the second mirror be changed so they they reference the `/dev/disk/by-id` instead of `/dev/sdX`?

```
user@pc:~$ sudo zpool status
  pool: storage
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 8h30m with 0 errors on Sun May 28 08:54:48 2017
config:

    NAME                                  STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    storage                               ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                            ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST2000AS0002-1NA12Z_Z840MHWP  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-ST2000AS0002-1NA12Z_Z840MHTQ  ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1                            ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd                               ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde                               ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Comment: Did you manage to change the vdevs in /dev/sdx to /dev/disk/by-id/.. ?

Answer (score 6):

You simply need to export and re-import your pool with a different default search directory for devices (`-d` option).

For example:

```
zpool export storage
zpool import storage -d /dev/disk/by-id
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with ZFS on linux (I'm guessing this is a problem peculiar to linux, Solaris and FreeBSD wouldn't have that kind of device name schizophrenia...) but you might try detaching and reattaching the drives as disk-by-id (be sure to give each time to fully resilver)

```
zpool detach mirror-1 sdd
zpool attach mirror-1 /dev/disk/sdd-by-id
<wait until zpool status shows it's rebuilt...>
```

and so on...